# How can I help Powershell to find the remote server?

Tags: powershell, remote-server

Using the Enter-PSSession cmdlet, I get an error that the server is not found.  However, I can immediately ping the same server, so I wondering what the error really is and how to fix it.  e.g.

[image]

Note: I can use RDP to connect to this server and normally do that.  However, if I could use PowerShell remote sessions my work would be easier and faster.

Tried again with an ip-based connection (using the ip from the ping, above) and an explicit credential.  Failed with a new error:

[image]

Comment: Can you remote into it using the IP? Are you in a domain environment? Are your connections set to private? Are the computers in aduc?

Comment: It’s not failing because it can’t find the server. It’s failing because of permissions/authentication issues. 

Is remoting turned on for the server? Is the firewall off?

Or have you tried doing New-PSSession $server first?

Comment: I can remote into it using RDP.  In fact, I have to since the powershell remote session does not work.